# Grails version >= 3 very slow when executing call to Oracle java network tracing API

Tags: java, oracle, grails

I have a Grails REST application (version 2.5.1) that traces routes on a road network. The network is hosted in an Oracle DB as an LOD Network. The performance of this application is very good, just a few seconds to return a complete route.

I have tried to upgrade this application to a later version of Grails, most recently (4.0.3). When it comes to tracing a route it is horrendously slow (about 20 minutes compared to a few seconds). The code consists of services mainly with a controller to kick it off. There is no domain class and the response is formatted as a GeoJSON linestring.

The slowness occurs when a call is made to the NetworkAnalyst.shortestPathDijkstra method in the Oracle Network API.

I have updated the jar files being used to Oracle 19c versions and also tried JDK 8 & JDK 11 without any significant change.

Does anyone have any insight into why changing the Grails version would have such a significant impact on the speed of this code?

Comment: "The slowness occurs when a call is made to the NetworkAnalyst.shortestPathDijkstra method in the Oracle Network API." - It doesn't make sense that the version of Grails being used would affect the performance of code in the Oracle Network API.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a new empty Grails app (grails create-app ...) and then adding in the minimal code to test that call. Also, check to see if it is firing multiple (duplicate) network calls, as you might be getting throttled by the API, maybe?

Comment: @Jeff Scott Brown I don't understand why the Grails version affects the speed, but that is essentially the only change between the 2 versions.

Comment: @nickdos I think I will try to do that when I get time. That will hopefully give some further insight, but the code will still be fairly complex

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to get the NetworkIO object by calling LODNetworkManager.getCachedNetworkIO() rather than LODNetworkManager.getNetworkIO()

Nothing to do with the Grails version, but that must have changed when I updated to Grails 4.